# Modify expression in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file so that each line is like this:

```
A|B
```

How can I change it using a regex so that I can have this as final result:

```
A|1|||B|||
```

Example: **1ARC00138|34** results in **1ARC00138|1|||34|||**

Comment: I'm going to write what is now becoming my standard comment on "do it for me" regex questions once more: What did you try? What didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find:

```
(.+)\|(.+)
```

Replace with:

```
\1|1|||\2|||
```

Answer (score 0):

This replacement regex:

```
s/^(.*)\|(.*)$/\1|1|||\2|||/
```